# Expected value question

Tags: expected-value

Say I am rolling a 20-sided die. What is the expected number of rolls to have rolled each number?

I haven't taken statistics in a while so my syntax might be off but this question has been bugging me for a while. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: is this a homework question? please add self study tag

Comment: Hey, this isn't a homework question, it's related to a forum event that I am helping run that involves rolling all possible numbers on a 20 sided-die. Just wanted to make sure that the event is running for an appropriate amount of time that makes "winning" not impossible/highly improbable. I've added the tag though

Comment: See posts on the [coupon collector problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector).

Comment: I removed the [tag:self-study] tag because it was put there only under peer pressure and does not seem appropriate. :-)

Comment: Given the objective of the exercise, as provided in your comment, you shouldn't be satisfied with knowing just the expected number of rolls. Anyhow, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem . Can you show us a picture of the 20-sided die?.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for the comments - I will look into the Coupon collector problem. The dice in question is a virtual dice.